# Having problem with installing apt-fast

Tags: apt, apt-fast

I'm trying to install apt-fast, and I use bellow commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apt-fast/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

After updating my sources I receive following warnings:

```
.
.
.
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 21.2 MB in 13min 19s (26.5 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And when I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

It says that there is no apt-fast packages:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-fast
```

Why this happen?

thanks

Comment: change your server mirror following this article: http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure then update again.

Comment: This link useful
http://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=89492.0
work for me on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

According to https://launchpad.net/~apt-fast/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages it is not available as a ppa for trusty. You could go to https://launchpad.net/~apt-fas and ask them for a update or download it your self from the source at https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast